# On maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ and $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Show for the ideal $I=(y-x^2,xy+10x-5)$ if it's maximal in $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ or in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$.

To show that $I$ is a maximal ideal I would usually define a map $f:\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]\to\mathbb{Q}$ (respectively for $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$) and show that the map is a surjective homomorphism, and if we show that $\ker(f)=I$, then we can apply the isomorphism theorem to conclude that $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/I\cong \mathbb{C}$ and because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field it follows that $I$ is a field. But I can't see how I could define such a map in this case. It seems to me that $I$ is not maximal in either $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ or in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that the instances where there is a homomorphism $f:\Bbb Q[X,Y]\to \Bbb Q$ such that $\ker f=I$ are very rare, even among the ones where $I$ actually is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2,XY+10X-5)\cong k[X]/(X^3+10X-5).$$
Now, which polynomials are irreducible over $\Bbb C$?

And which well-known criterion is sometimes helpful to prove that a polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$?

Note also that in your example, $\Bbb Q[X,Y]/I$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ but to a cubic extension of it.